# Writing JUnit test for a private constructor passing parameters

Tags: java

I need to write a unit test to test getRequired() method here by passing test data to private constructor private Example(String a, String b). Please help me with this.

```
public class Example {

private String str1 = null;
private String str2 = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Example e = new Example(args[0], args[1]);
    String req = e.getRequired();
    System.out.println(req);
}

private Example(String a, String b)
{
    str1 = new String(a);
    str2 = new String(b);
}

private String getRequired()
{
   //code using str1 and str2 here
   return "success";
}
```

}

Comment: everything is private in there ... how do you want to test that from another test class ?

Comment: So, there is no way I can test getRequired() method?

Comment: You could probably use reflection to access and un-privatify the constructor...

Comment: I thought may be I can create an instance to this private constructor and call that using a public method. Something like this:

Comment: @tobias_k - Can you please explain me how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## From a black box testing standpoint

This code can't be tested.  You can't even instantiate it, so there's no realistic way to go about this.  There's no sense in testing something that can't be used like this.

If you want to *make* it testable, then you have to expose a static method to create instances of it.  If that's a singleton or a factory, that's up to you - it's not apparent just from what you're showing us, but at least this would allow you to test the construction of it *without* really worrying about the private constructor.

You'd also have to make accessors to get at the fields, but make them package-private.

Further, invocations such as `new String(String)` in this case aren't needed, and may only serve to confuse you.  You're passing in a `String`, so you don't need to create a *new* one.

Lastly, from a testing standpoint, `getRequired()` is tough to test; unless it mutates the state of the instance (which, again, you need to use to verify anything), there's no point to test it.  It'll only ever return `"success"`.

```
public class Example {

    private String str1 = null;
    private String str2 = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e = new Example(args[0], args[1]);
        String req = e.getRequired();
        System.out.println(req);
    }

    private Example(String a, String b) {
        str1 = new String(a);
        str2 = new String(b);
    }
    
    String getStr1() {
        return str1;
    }
    
    String getStr2() {
        return str2;
    }
    
    private String getRequired() {
        //code using str1 and str2 here
        return "success";
    }
    
    public static Example getNewInstance(String a, String b) {
        return new Example(a, b);
    }
}
```

## From a white box testing standpoint

You can only use reflection to get at the private constructor and the fields to verify that they are set.

```
@Test
public void testExample() throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, NoSuchFieldException {
    Constructor<Example> exampleConstructor = Example.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, String.class);
    exampleConstructor.setAccessible(true);
    Example example = exampleConstructor.newInstance("foo", "bar");

    // verify
    Field str1 = example.getClass().getDeclaredField("str1");
    Field str2 = example.getClass().getDeclaredField("str2");
    str1.setAccessible(true);
    str2.setAccessible(true);

    assertThat("foo", equalTo(str1.get(example)));
    assertThat("bar", equalTo(str2.get(example)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two other options.

Typically a private constructor implies that the class can not be sub-classed, and that by design the user of the exported API is not able to call the constructor directly. In this case there could be a public static factory method that would be implemented. This allows for instance control, which is not implemented below.

```
    public static Example newInstance(String a, String b){
      return new Example(a, b);
    }
```

The other option, if you must test the constructor directly, is to promote the access modifier to the default, "package private", modifier.

```
    Example(String a, String b){...}
```

You could add your unit test in the same package and test that way. Upgrading an access modifier from private to default in order to facilitate testing should not be a concern.